# Restricting page access with passport.js and express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I have a server set up to authenticate user login, so far I was able to successfully authenticate user and redirect them to the success page (as well as redirect them back to the login page if failed). However, I can't use my own express middleware to restrict user if they are not logged in, for some reason my `req.isAuthenticate()` check in the middleware is always `false`. I feel like my session info is not stored when logging in, but I'm not sure.

Here's my setup (note that I use `express-flash-2` instead of `connect-flash` therefore the `req.flash()`)

**In server.js**

```
// ...
var flash = require('express-flash-2');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
// ...

server.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
server.use(flash());
server.use(passport.initialize());
server.use(passport.session());

passport.use(auth_controller.authStrategy);
passport.serializeUser(auth_controller.authSerializer);
passport.deserializeUser(auth_controller.authDeserializer);

server.get('/maintenance_login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});
server.post('/maintenance_login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/maintenance',
    failureRedirect: '/maintenance_login',
    failureFlash: true
}));

// This does basically the same as above
// server.post('/maintenance_login', (req, res, next) => {
//     passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
//         if (err) { return next(err); }
//         if (!user) { return res.redirect('/maintenance_login'); }
//
//         req.logIn(user, function(err) {
//             if (err) { return next(err); }
//             console.log('is authenticated?: ' + req.user); // this returns true
//             return res.redirect('/maintenance');
//         });
//     })(req, res, next);
// });

server.get('/maintenance:query?', auth_controller.restrict, maintenance_controller.maintenance_list);
```

**In auth_controller.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

var User = require('../models/user');

exports.authStrategy = new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, function (email, password, done) {
    User.authenticate(email, password, function(err, user) {
        // success message

        // error message
        done(err, user, err ? { message: err.message } : null);
    });
});

exports.authSerializer = function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
};

exports.authDeserializer = function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
};

exports.restrict = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('is authenticated?: ' + req.isAuthenticated()); // This always returns false
    if (req.isUnauthenticated()) {
        res.flash('error', 'Access denied, please log in.');
        return res.redirect('/maintenance_login');
    }
    return next();
}
```

Again, my issue is that whenever I was successfully logged in, I got kicked back to `/maintenance_login` and the flash showing `"Access denied, please log in."`. Which means that `req.isUnauthenticated()` in the restrict middleware returns `true`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that missing the `.Strategy` is crucial. Changing `var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');` to `var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;` fixes this issue. Incase anyone else is having the same problem.